# How to determine the generating function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

So I have $$\overset{*}{F} = \overset{*}{F}_{n-1} + \overset{*}{F}_{n-2} + g(n)$$ where $\overset{*}{F}$ is NOT a Fibonacci number for $n \geq 2$.

$g(n)$ is any function $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$. And $\overset{*}{F}_0 = g(0)$ and $\overset{*}{F}_1 = g(1)$.

I think that $\overset{*}{F}_n$ would be a sequence of $g(n)$s. Actually, I have found that
$$\overset{*}{F}_n = f_{n-1}\cdot g(0) + f_n\cdot g(1) + f_{n-1}\cdot g(2) + f_{n-2}\cdot g(3) + \dots + f_1\cdot g(n)$$ Here $f_n$ is the n-th Fibonacci number. So to clarify, let n = 5, then:
$$\overset{*}{F}_5 = f_4\cdot g(0) + f_5\cdot g(1) + f_4\cdot g(2) + f_3\cdot g(3) + f_2\cdot g(4) + f_1\cdot g(5)$$
$$\overset{*}{F}_5 = 3\cdot g(0) + 5\cdot g(1) + 3\cdot g(2) + 2\cdot g(3) + 1\cdot g(4) + 1\cdot g(5)$$

**My question** is how to find the generating function of $\overset{*}{F}_n$ if $$G(x) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0}g(n)\cdot x^n$$
applies?

I have difficulties representing the generating function of the Fibonacci numbers reversed. Even though that I know that the regular g.f. $F(x) = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2}$

Maybe I should somehow transform this:
$$\overset{*}{F}_n = f_{n-1}\cdot g(0)x^0 + f_n\cdot g(1)x^1 + f_{n-1}\cdot g(2)x^2 + f_{n-2}\cdot g(3)x^3 + \dots + f_1\cdot g(n)x^n$$
and use $G(x)$ to get the generating function for all $\overset{*}{F}_n$?

Comment: Just multiply the $n^{th}$ equation by $z^n$ and start to sum from $n$.
$$\overset{*}{F}(z) - g(0) - g(1)z = z(\overset{*}{F}(z)-g(0)) + z^2\overset{*}{F}(z) + (G(z) - g(0) - g(1)z)\\
\iff (1 - z - z^2)\overset{*}{F}(z) = G(z) - g(0)z
\implies\overset{*}{F}(z) = \frac{G(z) - g(0)z}{1 -z -z^2}
$$

Comment: oops, I mean start to sum from  $n = 2$.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you!

Comment: @achillehui Would you care to convert your comment to an answer to get the question off the "unanswered" list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment turned answer per request.

Just multiply the $n^{th}$ equation by $z^n$ and start to sum from $n = 2$.

$$
\overbrace{\overset{*}{F}(z) - g(0) - g(1)z}^{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\overset{*}{F}_n z^n}
= 
\overbrace{z(\overset{*}{F}(z)-g(0))}^{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \overset{*}{F}_{n-1} z^n
} 
+ 
\overbrace{z^2\overset{*}{F}(z)}^{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \overset{*}{F}_{n-2} z^n
}
+
\overbrace{(G(z) - g(0) - g(1)z)}
^{
\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty g(n) z^n
}
\\ 
\iff (1 - z - z^2)\overset{*}{F}(z) = G(z) - g(0)z\\
\implies \overset{*}{F}(z) = \frac{G(z) - g(0)z}{1 -z -z^2}$$